# How to exclude a word with regex in ansible playbook?

Tags: python, regex, automation, ansible, vmware

I am trying to develop a Ansible playbook to select and display the list of datastores in vCenter, however for validation purpose I should not select the datastore that contains the `local` or `Local` in its name.

For example consider the following 4 datastores:

- `datastore:local8`
- `TQAESXHOST05-Local01`
- `vnx_dwcesxbl_ecom_lun7`
- `tqaesx37d_1`

It should only select:

- `vnx_dwcesxbl_ecom_lun7`
- `tqaesx37d_1`

Should **not** select:

- `datastore:local8`
- `TQAESXHOST05-Local01`

Here is the playbook

```yaml
tasks:
- name: List of datastores with calculated values
  set_fact:
    ds_size_list: "{{ ds_size_list | default([]) + [{ 'name' : item.name, 'capacity' : item.capacity, 'freeSpace' : item.freeSpace, 'freeSpaceAfter' : freeSpaceAfter | int, 'percentFreeAfter' : percentFreeAfter | int }] }}"
  with_items: "{{ datastore_info.datastores }}"
  vars:
    freeSpaceAfter: "{{ item.freeSpace - (vm_size_b | int) }}"
    percentFreeAfter: "{{ freeSpaceAfter | int / item.capacity * 100 }}"
  when: item.accessible
  when: when: item.name is regex(?!local) #should exclude datastores containing "local" word
```

Need suggestions on writing the regex expression to exclude the datastores containing the word `local`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex for this is probably an overkill. You can use the [`in`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-tests.in) test of Jinja to assert that a sub-string is contained in a string — since a string is just a sequence of characters, the `in` test works on strings.

So, given:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.name }}"
  loop: "{{ datastore_info.datastores }}"
  when: 
    - item.accessible
    - "'Local' not in item.name"
    - "'local' not in item.name"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}"
  vars:
    datastore_info:
      datastores:
        - name: datastore:local8
          accessible: yes
        - name: TQAESXHOST05-Local01
          accessible: yes
        - name: vnx_dwcesxbl_ecom_lun7
          accessible: yes
        - name: tqaesx37d_1
          accessible: yes
```

This yield:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=datastore:local8) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=TQAESXHOST05-Local01) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=vnx_dwcesxbl_ecom_lun7) => 
  msg: vnx_dwcesxbl_ecom_lun7
ok: [localhost] => (item=tqaesx37d_1) => 
  msg: tqaesx37d_1
```

And if you don't care about the casing of `local` at all (`Local`, `lOcAl`, ...), you can even simplify it further with the [`lower` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.lower) and do:

```yaml
when: 
  - item.accessible
  - "'local' not in item.name | lower"
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"**Exclude the datastores containing the word 'local' or 'Local'.**"*

A: [Reject the items where the attribute](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.rejectattr) *name* can [*search*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) Python regex `'[lL]ocal'`. For example, given the data below for testing

```yaml
    datastores:
      - {name: datastore:local8, capacity: 100, freeSpace: 10}
      - {name: TQAESXHOST05-Local01, capacity: 200, freeSpace: 20}
      - {name: vnx_dwcesxbl_ecom_lun7, capacity: 300, freeSpace: 30}
      - {name: tqaesx37d_1, capacity: 400, freeSpace: 40}
```

the task

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ds_size_list: "{{ ds_size_list|default([]) +
                          [{'name': item.name,
                            'capacity': item.capacity,
                            'freeSpace' : item.freeSpace,
                            'percentFreeAfter': percentFreeAfter|int }] }}"
      loop: "{{ datastores|rejectattr('name', 'search', '[lL]ocal') }}"
      vars:
        percentFreeAfter: "{{ item.freeSpace|int / item.capacity|int * 100 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ds_size_list:
  - capacity: 300
    freeSpace: 30
    name: vnx_dwcesxbl_ecom_lun7
    percentFreeAfter: 10
  - capacity: 400
    freeSpace: 40
    name: tqaesx37d_1
    percentFreeAfter: 10
```

---

If you want to keep all attributes of the items you can [*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) additional attributes. This simplifies the code. For example, the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ds_size_list: "{{ ds_size_list|default([]) +
                          [item|combine({'percentFreeAfter': percentFreeAfter|int})] }}"
      loop: "{{ datastores|rejectattr('name', 'search', '[lL]ocal') }}"
      vars:
        percentFreeAfter: "{{ item.freeSpace|int / item.capacity|int * 100 }}"
```